C++: Inheriting the const assignment operator defined in the base class for the derived type
Many, many, many posts about inheriting operator=, with the usual answer being "it's overshadowed by the implicitly defined one, use using Base::operator= if you know what you're doing".
Here's a hopefully slightly different question.  Consider the following in which base class A knows about the exact type of the derived class:
#include <iostream>

template <typename E>
struct A {
    E& operator= (const E& other) {
      std::cout << "A<E>::op=\n";
      return *(E*)this;
    }

    E& operator= (E& other) {
      std::cout << "A<E>::op no const=\n";
      return *(E*)this;
    }
};

struct B : public A<B> {
    using A<B>::operator=;
};

int main () {
  B x, y;
  x = y;
  const B z;
  x = z;
}

In the main function, when calling x = y,  the method E& A<E>::operator= (E& other) with E = B is called, as expected.  However, x = z does not call E& A<E>::operator= (const E& other).
Why?  (Note that this is a question about behavior, not style :-) )

Unrelated: You don't need the sledgehammer (E*). Just make it return *static_cast<E*>(this);


Why?

Because x = z uses the implicitly defined
B& B::operator=(const B&)

and the implicitly defined
A& A::operator=(const A&)
// instantiated as:
A<B>& A<B>::operator=(const A<B>&)

The implicit definitions are not removed just because you bring the base class operators out of hiding. See [class.copy]/24:

A using-declaration ([namespace.udecl]) that brings in from a base class an assignment operator with a parameter type that could be that of a copy/move assignment operator for the derived class is not considered an explicit declaration of such an operator and does not suppress the implicit declaration of the derived class operator; the operator introduced by the using-declaration is hidden by the implicitly-declared operator in the derived class.

The reason why the other case, x = y, instead uses E& A::operator= (E& other) is because it's a better match since it doesn't need to convert y to a const&.

@TedLyngmo: Thanks so much for your time and expertise!  I think what confuses me still is that I am expecting the using statement to import a properly typed operator= into B, so that no implicit definition is required.  Why isn't it the case?  Is there a way to express the intended code without writing proxy methods?  Cheers!

@Michaël You're welcome! I updated the answer to deal with that question.

Fantastic, thank you again!  So class.copy section 18, which states "If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly," does not include in "explicitly declare" one definition imported with using.  Surprises me a bit, but good to know!  Thanks Ted!

@Michaël I updated the answer to answer that too :-) Cheers!

It sure is acceptable, thanks again! — although I'm still wondering if there is a way to express the intended code without extra proxy functions, but I gather the answer is no.  I've been into the habit of waiting a couple two three days before accepting answers, in case someone else wants to chime in :-)

@Michaël Great! No, I don't see a way to express the intended code exacly. You could add B& operator=(B&) = default; to make a const B use the base class assignment operator, but still, that seems like just half of what you want.
